# Extjs store deep clone issue

Tags: jquery, extjs, clone, extjs-stores

I have a store. On the load event of the store, I am doing somethign like this.

```
 'load': function (store, rec, success, options) {

            var data = store.getRange();
            var data2 = store.getRange();

        }
```

If I say `data == data2`, I get `false`. Which means `data` and `data2` do not points to same reference location.

Assume the store conatins multiple records & each record has a property by name `IsUpdated` which is set to `false` by default

At this point if I say `console.log(data[0].data.IsUpdated)` & `console.log(data2[0].data.IsUpdated)` both returns false (which is correct).

Now. If I say `data[0].data.IsUpdated = true` & then run `console.log(data[0].data.IsUpdated)` & `console.log(data2[0].data.IsUpdated)` **both returns true**.

This means both data and data2 points to same reference. I am not sure how to fix this issue. I have tried to deep clone the record using `jQuery.extend(true, {}, data)` but even this is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ext.clone](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext-method-clone):

```
var data2 = Ext.clone(data);
```

This way, when you set `data[0].data.IsUpdated = true`, in data2 `data2[0].data.IsUpdated` will remain false.